# kubernetes get absolute resource units

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is it possible to get K8s resource limits in *absolute units*? By default we get a human-readable units (like Mi, Gi, for memory) and m for CPU:

```
$ kubectl get pod ndbmysqld-1 -o yaml | grep -A 6 " resources:" | grep "limits:" -A 2
      limits:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 512Mi
--
      limits:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 256Mi
```

But my Pods have all different units, see this one:

```
      limits:
        cpu: "1"
        memory: 214748364800m
```

NB: 214748364800m is apparently 200Mi...

Any way to get all units aligned?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that can be possible, you have to normalize the values manually in every pod.

Answer (score 2):

2 ways to do this: use numfmt. You can use this to reformat numeric columns which is really convenient if you pull out tsv data from kubectl. This is what I'd recommend.

```
kubectl get pods -o json |jq -r '.items[]|.metadata as $m|.spec.containers[].resources[]|[$m.name, .memory]|@tsv' \
|numfmt --field=2 --from=auto
```

alternatively you can approximate it in plain jq (if you don't have numfmt or you need it in jq for differently-formatted output):

```
kubectl get pods -o json \
|jq -r 'def units: .|capture("(?<n>[0-9]+)(?<u>[A-Za-z]?)")|. as $v|($v.n|tonumber)*(if $v.u=="" then 1 else pow(10;3*("m_KMGTPE"|index($v.u)-1)) end); 
.items[].spec.containers[].resources[].memory|units'
```

Highlighting just the function I defined in there:

```
def units: 
 .|capture("(?<n>[0-9]+)(?<u>[A-Za-z]?)")
  |. as $v
  |($v.n|tonumber)*(
    if $v.u=="" then 1 
    else pow(10;3*("m_KMGTPE"|index($v.u)-1)) 
    end)
```

what this does is capture the number part and the first character of the suffix as 'n' and 'u', then returns 'n' times 10^3*(index of the suffix in "m_KMGTPE" minus one). eg for 'm' the index is 0 so it multiplies by 10^-3, for 1 the index is 2 so it multiplies by 10^3, and so on.

Comment: 256Mi should be 256*1024*1024, not 256*1000*1000

Answer (score 0):

- For CPU Fractional requests are allowed. Info is below
- **You can express** `memory` **as a** **plain integer** or as a fixed-point number

[**Meaning of CPU**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#meaning-of-cpu)

> Limits and requests for CPU resources are measured in cpu units. One
> cpu, in Kubernetes, is equivalent to 1 vCPU/Core for cloud providers
> and 1 hyperthread on bare-metal Intel processors.
>
> Fractional requests are allowed. A Container with
> spec.containers[].resources.requests.cpu of 0.5 is guaranteed half as
> much CPU as one that asks for 1 CPU. The expression 0.1 is equivalent
> to the expression 100m, which can be read as "one hundred millicpu".
> Some people say "one hundred millicores", and this is understood to
> mean the same thing. A request with a decimal point, like 0.1, is
> converted to 100m by the API, and precision finer than 1m is not
> allowed. For this reason, the form 100m might be preferred.
>
> CPU is always requested as an absolute quantity, never as a relative
> quantity; 0.1 is the same amount of CPU on a single-core, dual-core,
> or 48-core machine.

[**Meaning of memory**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#meaning-of-memory)

Limits and requests for memory are measured in bytes. You can express `memory` as a plain integer or as a fixed-point number using one of these suffixes: E, P, T, G, M, K. You can also use the power-of-two equivalents: Ei, Pi, Ti, Gi, Mi, Ki. For example, the following represent roughly the same value:

```
128974848, 129e6, 129M, 123Mi
```